# how do i make gruntjs do concat, uglify, and watch when i save my files?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a gruntjs file which has a registerTask('default',['concat','uglify','watch']); 
If i save my scss files, it will update my css files. But if I want to have Grunt concat and uglify my JS, I have to go into terminal, exit out of the watch, then run the grunt command. Its really annoying.

Is there any way to have grunt run all these tasks when i save any of my JS and/or css files? Without needing to go into terminal every time? Heres my gruntfile if that helps.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                sassDir: 'sass',
                cssDir: 'css'
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: '**/*.scss',
            tasks: ['compass']
        }
    },
    concat: {
          options: {
            separator: '\n\n'
          },
          dist: {
            src: ['js-game/*.js'],
            dest: 'js/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
          }

    },
    uglify:{
        options:{mangle:false},
        my_target:{
            files:{'js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js' : ['js/<%= pkg.name %>.js']

            }
        }
    }       
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default',['concat','uglify','watch']);
```

}

thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add:

```
scripts: {
  files: ['**/*.js'],
  tasks: ['jshint'],
}
```

to the watch task it should work, you might need:

```
scripts: {
files: ['**/*.js'],
tasks: ['jshint'],
options: {
    spawn: false,
  }
}
```

So in your Gruntfile.js above it would be something like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
```

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

```
compass: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            sassDir: 'sass',
            cssDir: 'css'
        }
    }
},
watch: {
    css: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['compass']
    },
    scripts: {
      files: ['**/*.js'],
      tasks: ['jshint'],
      options: {
        spawn: false,
      }
    }
},
concat: {
      options: {
        separator: '\n\n'
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['js-game/*.js'],
        dest: 'js/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }

},
uglify:{
    options:{mangle:false},
    my_target:{
        files:{'js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js' : ['js/<%= pkg.name %>.js']

        }
    }
}       
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default',['concat','uglify','watch']);
}
```

That should hopefully do it.

Comment: hey thanks Stuart. It works but it works as the same way I had it. BUT I think I'm realizing that gruntjs cant do what I'm thinking. It will perform all the tasks when the 'grunt' command is run it the terminal, but won't run them all when i save the files. Maybe that's just a sass thing? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can added multiple tasks to watch. So if you wanted to concat and uglify on save you could do like this:

`watch: {
    css: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['compass']
    },
    scripts: {
      files: ['js-game/*.js'],
      tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
      options: {
        spawn: false,
      }
    }
},`

i hope this helps!